# how does this expression " -~x " work in java

Tags: java, binary, operating-system, bit-manipulation, bit

i'm learning bits operation but i have one dought in this -~x expression.

i'm following this [link](https://www.techiedelight.com/bit-hacks-part-1-basic/) and i coudn't able to understand how this expression handle positive case and negative case.

## in the bit article

> -x = ~x + 1;

> -~x = x + 1 (by replacing x by ~x)

i couldn't able to understand how this expression work.

let's say if the value x = 4 then this will convert it to 5 and if the value is -4 and then it will give -3 output.
**but the question is how it deals with positive or negative number**.

according to my observation negative number store in 2's complement form and then add 1 but if the value is already positive then how this will work?

Comment: You have an algebraic proof that `-~x == x + 1` right there in your question, it doesn't depend on `x` being negative

Comment: @harold so basically this is a constant expression.

Comment: Do you understand how [2's complement](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/two-s-complement) works?

Comment: @HeikoRibberink yes i have idea how 2's complement work.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you're asking how the second formula follows out of the first algebraic proof? If so, my answer is as follows: if we were to rewrite the first formula as `-A = ~A + 1;`, and we were to replace `A` by `~x`, we get: `-~x = ~~x + 1`. We can simplify `~~x` as `x`, making the formula `-~x = x + 1`, hence the second formula follows out of the first.

Comment: @HeikoRibberink thanks for sharing your answer and now i understand how the expression is evaluated.